# Where to store my Firebase Private Key for Node App

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, firebase

I just setup the **Node SDK** for **firebase** and after reading their documentation, I'm not sure where I should be storing the `ServiceAccount.json` file that contains my private key.

Their documentation made it seem like it should be stored locally on my computer but my **node** app is deployed to hosting provider so that doesn't seem right.

I followed their advice and setup the environment variable

> GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='path/to/file/on/my/computer'

but I don't understand how that will work once I deploy it to my hosting provider.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Best practice not to deploy your credentials to whatever service you're using where they can viewed by others. If you don't already have it, install `dotenv` package from npm

```
npm install dotenv
```

Create a `variables.env` file in your root folder. `dotenv` then loads your variables into `process.env`.

```
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='YOUR_CREDENTIALS'
```

goes into your `variables.env`  file.

As early as possible in your app, preferably where you instantiate it, import variables into your app

```
require('dotenv').config({ path: 'variables.env' });
```

Now your credentials can be accessed throughout your app through
`process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`.

If your using `git`, check the `.gitignore` file has the line `*.env`. This ensures that your credentials are ignored when uploading your app but are still available to you.

Comment: Thanks St_Mute but one more quick question!  I'm using dotenv already and right now in my env file I have GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='/path'.  The credientials in the Service Account JSON file is an object with 10 key:value pairs.  Should be be copying that entire object as a string into my .env file?

Comment: @bzlight - have you figure that out? should I stringify the credential.json from firebase and put that as the value of GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS? or maybe extract only the private key inside of the json to the .env file?

Comment: Im guessing GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/the/local/path/to/the/json/file/in/your/machine/. Then just use `var serviceAccount = require(process.env. GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS);`